# How to enable libcerf with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to graph both FresnelC(x) and FresnelS(x). There is [this example](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.5/Fresnel.html) which says that libcerf must be used but I am unsure how to use it. When I run gnuplot and try

```
plot [-4:4] FresnelC(x)
```

I get the message

```
undefined function: FresnelC
```

How do I enable libcerf with gnuplot?

Comment: No idea - I see https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/blob/04a11cefe2829e63e6cb72c17f24f90c86901233/src/eval.c#L243 , I also have +LIBCERF , I have gnuplog 5.4 patchlevel 2 on archlinux, and I can reproduce - I do not have FresnelC nor FresnelS functions. But functions `cerf` `cdawson` `erfi` and `faddeeva` work. This is odd. I have no function in `nm -D /usr/lib/libcerf.so.2 | grep FresnelC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your gnuplot executable reports +LIBCERF as part of the output from `show version long` then it was indeed configured with the cerf library.

However the FresnelC function is part of the greatly expanded support for complex special functions provided in the development version (gnuplot 5.5).  It is not present in any of the "stable" releases through 5.4.  Note that the demo page you linked to is from the demo collection for the development version.

A summary of new features introduced in the development version is here:
[Development Version](http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.5/loc192.html)

Comment: Do you know how I can download version 5.5?

Comment: The usual recipe: clone from the SourceForge git repository, ./configure, make.   If you're on Windows you might find a usable snapshot in the 'testing' directory of the download page.